# About refinements of order at most $d+1$

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

I am a little confused about the definition of covering dimension of a topological space. In particular, when defining the dimension of a space $X$, we take the minimum over all natural numbers such that every open cover of $X$ has a open refinement of order **at most** $n+1$.

Why at most? What is an example of a topological space of covering dimension $d$ with an open cover which has a refinement of order at most $d+1$, but not a refinement of order precisely $d+1$?

Edit: for sake of clarity, here are the relevant definitions, as stated by Munkres, word by word, in paragraph 50 of his book "Topology":

A collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of the space $X$ is said to have order $m+1$ if some point of $X$ lies in $m+1$ elements of $\mathcal A$, and no point of $X$ lies in more than $m+1$ elements of $\mathcal A$.

A space $X$ is said to be finite dimenstional il there is some integer $m$ such that for every open covering $\mathcal A$ of $X$, there is an open covering $\mathcal B$ which refines $\mathcal A$ and has order at most $m+1$. The topological dimension of $X$ is defined to be the smallest value of $m$ for which this statement holds.

Second edit, possibly a weaker question which does not involve the notion of dimension: given a topological space $X$ and an open cover $\mathcal U$ of order $m$, is it always possible to find an open refinement of $\mathcal U$ of order $m+1$?

Comment: Perhaps take a disk with line segment attached?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip And what cover?

Comment: Pick any cover you want. You'll be able to refine it on the line segment part to have order 2 and on the disk part to have order 3.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I don't see what you mean, if it has order $3$ on the disk, then it has order $3$ globally.

Comment: ah I misunderstood your question.

Comment: And in general, it seems like a metric space can never be an example, since whenever we have an intersection of open sets, we could always add a smaller open set contained in that intersection to raise the order of the cover.

Comment: I don't think you quoted the definition correctly. The "at most" is within the definition of order. The covering dimension is the minimal n such that every open cover has a refinement of order n+1. The order of a refinement is the largest number of open sets any point in the space is contained in, which can be rephrased as "any point is contained in at most n+1 open sets of the cover."

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Any decent reference I know, like Munkres, Engelking and Pears (but not Wikipedia) states the definition this way. The only possible variation is wheter you want to start with a finite cover or not, but this does not concern the matter of the question.

Comment: I don't have a physical copy of Munkres in front of me, but here is a definition I found attributed to him, which agrees with what I said:  A topological space  is said to have the Lebesgue covering dimension <∞ if  is the smallest non-negative integer with the property that each open cover of  has a refinement in which no point of  is included in more than +1 elements.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I honestly see no point in keeping on debating the definition. I have a physical copy of Munkres with me, and the definition clearly contains the expression "at most". But this is not really relevant at all, if you believe in a different definition of this concept, let us say that my question is about a different notion, the "arnett covering dimension", which is being defined in this very question precisely the way I have defined it.

Comment: will you transcribe Munkres's definition exactly?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip done

Comment: Okay I finally see what you are asking. Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a space like $\Bbb Q \cup (0,1)$ in the topology it inherits ffrom $\Bbb R$ a cover for it will have a refinement that is order $1$ (i.e. pairwise disjoint) on the rationals outside $(0,1)$ but order $2$ on the $(0,1)$ part, making the order for the whole cover 2 as well. The "at most" clause is mostly to work for such "hybrid" spaces where the so-called "local dimension" is not constant across the space. I often get confused by the "off by 1" nature of the definition (order 1 = disjoint, order 2: at most pairwise intersecting, which can be achieved in $\Bbb R$ etc.)

A space like $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ has a cover of order $1$ (obvious ) but not *every* open cover of it has this property.
A boring observation but it shows the need for the "at most" clause if we consider all covers.

The covering definition is due to Lebesgue (early 20th century) but he could not prove rigorously that $\dim \Bbb R^n = n$. This is what Brouwer did later (via a detour, his own inductively defined dimension, "Dimensionsgrad" (papers in German..) using his own fixed point theorem as a tool... Finally topologists had a way to prove that all $\Bbb R^n$ were not homeomorphic for different $n$ (the space-filling curves had seeded doubts: if the continuous image of $[0,1]$ can fill a solid ball continuously, what is our intuition worth?) This as a historical footnote.

Comment: I think your example has the same problem as the one in the comments, maybe my question is not clear but I don't know how to make it clearer. I am not looking for an open cover with different local orders at different points. I am looking for a topological space, if it exists, such that it has covering dimension $d$, but there is one cover of it which admits no refinements of orderd precisely $d+1$, but instead only refinements of order strictly less than $d+1$.

Comment: As a side note, the way I rember the definition, not to get confused with the $+1$ switch, is the following: the covering dimension of $X$ is $\min\{n\in \mathbb N: \text{for every open cover } \mathcal U \text { of } X \text{there is an open refinement } \mathcal V \text{ such that } \mathrm{dim} N(\mathcal V)\le n\}$, where $N(\mathcal V)$ is the nerve of the cover.

Comment: I still can not see why. If a space is $d$-dimensional, every open cover has a refinement of order at most $d+1$ (and there is at least one open cover which admits no refinements of order $d$), but why should every open cover have a refinement of order precisely $d+1$? I have added the definition I am using in the question.

Comment: @arnett the minimum must be **assumed** (that's why we use well-orderness of $\Bbb N$) This means there is at least one open cover $\mathcal{U}$ with a refinement of order at most $d+1$ but not $d$ (or we'd have at most $d$, contradicting the minimality)

Comment: I agree on this, that's precisely what I have said. But now I am asking if there can be also an open cover with a refinement of order $d$ but not one of order $d+1$. (Just one! Not every cover)

Comment: I have added a further edit. If you want and have time, you could take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X = \mathbb R^n$.

Every open cover has a refinement of order at most $n+1$.

The open cover $\{X\}$ has a refinement of order $1$, namely itself. We don't the full number $n+1$.